# Help replicating sci-fi texture

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to procedurally replicate the white fabric-like texture on this spaceship:

[image: (Image from Paul Chadeisson)]

So far, this is what my render looks like:

[image: My rendered image]

And here is my node setup:

[image: My node setup]

Basically, it's two sets of overlapping wave textures with distortion, subtracted against each other to make the "stippling" effect. Then I apply that to a bump node and combine that with a burlap texture normal map to give it that "fabric" look.

But it still doesn't look as good as the source image. I'm still struggling to get that randomized and grunge-y look that I see in the source photo. Any tips on how I might get my texture to look more like the source image? Thanks!

Edit: my blend file as requested:
[image]

Edit2: Added a better test render image, for comparison.

Comment: Hello, I'd suggest you upload the node setting in a blend file. That could help people to test around your solution. Thanks. Please use this link for uploading: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks! I just added my blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a displacement map. Using Blender 2.8, I used a space shuttle thermal tile texture to influence the height of a displacement node and plugged that into the Material Output displacement. You also need to enable "Displacement and Bump" in the Material Settings -> Surface -> Displacement settings.

I realize this isn't procedural, as I originally asked, and it's not the exact texture shown above, but it solves what I was trying to do in a relatively simple way.

Here's the texture I created, in case anyone wants to use it in their work. It's made from several images of NASA's Space Shuttle thermal blankets.

[image]